# Probe network for events and transactions while hosting on AWS ubuntu

Tags: go-ethereum, aws

My intention is to be able to log events and transactions on the ethereum chain, in order to display user updates in a standard http web application. if i am running geth on a AWS ubuntu server, i will be able to probe the chain with the web3js interface right? what is the correct way to probe the hosted chain for events and transactions to display in-app, without forcing the user to use a metamask plugin or web3 browser?

just diving into the eth dev world, with limited documentation resources. is there an easier way to probe the chian, like a web service or something? thanks

Comment: i suppose i can just use the etherscan api